# Live Broacasting Error. creates *.m3u.m3u

Tags: streaming, icecast, m3u

Greetings & Salutations one and all

I'm new to mixxx been using it for about 4hrs and its a brilliant piece of software so thanks once again for this amazing program. The issues i'm having is that it creates and double m3u.m3u. extension when I'm live broadcasting. I had issues with getting this to work but figured it out with lame.dll which I didn't have to rename as this solution is for version 1 and below.

It works now after putting the lame encoder.dll file into the mixxx folder, which I think might be the issue i'm not sure. the live broadcasting connects successfully and it connects to my icecast server without issue, however when I click on m3u on icecast admin page or connect directly to it the web e.g. http://externalIP:8000/stream it show me the m3u.m3u error, which is causing the streaming error as its creating a double m3u file and as we know only .m3u works not m3u.m3u. so I think its the encoding creating this double extension but I'm not sure hence the post. any ideas??

[mixxx m3u.m3u error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lrtU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configure a mount point in Mixxx.
Like `/stream.ogg` or `/radio.opus`, depending on the format/codec.

Also make sure that it does NOT end in m3u! The mountpoint is a *virtual* media file, not a playlist. The server will *automatically* generate *another* virtual file, a m3u playlist for it.

Comment: thank mate for the info should of been clearer on the .m3u file as I didn't create or rename the file its automatically creates the double m3u file extension. I have set it to mp3 and I have edited any of the mount point info left it a stream as still learning how to configure the xml file. managed to resolve the issue by installing mix on another computer and connect to the live stream e.g. server host icast to client Mixxx and it connects fine and streams.